# Using an array from one function in another function in same fragment

Tags: java, android

Im new to java and attempting to use `sampleTitles` from one function and use in another function. The data  in `sampleTitles` is dynamic and drawn from retrofit

Fragment.java

```
@BindView(R.id.customCarouselView) CarouselView customCarouselView; //butterknife

double[] sampleVotes = {
    8.9,4.2,
};

@Override
public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    
    connect();
}

private void connect() {

    //this array not passed to setViewListener 
    String[] sampleTitles = {
                "Test 1",
                "Test 2",
    };
                        
    customCarouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);
}

// To set custom views
ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
    @Override
    public View setViewForPosition(int position) {

        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_custom, null);

        TextView labelTextView = customView.findViewById(R.id.labelTextView);
        labelTextView.setText(sampleTitles[position]);  //want to use sampleTitles here from 
        connect(); function               

        return customView;
    }
};
```

Comment: In Java all variables have visibility scope. The place where the variable is visible in code. You can check this article for more information - https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope. Happy learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that array a global variable. So you can access it through the whole class.
Change your code as below. Also I advice you use `ArrayList` instead so you don't need to provide size of array at the time of initialisaion. Tell me if you face any problem.

```
 @BindView(R.id.customCarouselView) CarouselView customCarouselView; //butterknife


   double[] sampleVotes = {
            8.9,4.2,
    };

    List<String> sampleTitles = new ArrayList<String>(); //declare as global variable so you can access it

    @Override
        public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    
    connect();
    }

   private void connect() {

    //Do your insert operations in array here 
        sampleTitles.add("Test 1");
        sampleTitles.add("Test 2");
                        
        customCarouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);

    }

   // To set custom views
    ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {

            View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_custom, null);

            TextView labelTextView = customView.findViewById(R.id.labelTextView);
          
            labelTextView.setText(sampleTitles.get(position));  //you can access your array with this code               

            return customView;
        }
    };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230812/unable-to-use-in-local-variable-bindviews-not-applicable-to-local-variable-bu  pls check this question